# Using vlookup / index match for this circumstances

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

I have some data which are grouped like this:

1st group of data(gender): Male, Female 
2nd group of data(age): 12,13,14,15 
3rd group (score + grade): For each gender and their corresponding age, there is a range of the scores grade A,b,c,d

For example: For a 12yr old male, 40 points will correspond a C grade. While a 14yr old female, 50 points will correspond a B grade.

how can i use excel to help me such that when I enter the age, gender and score, the correspond grade will come out?

THank you so much.

Comment: Seems similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29516658/looking-up-multiple-items-in-a-table/29517989#29517989

Answer (score 0):

You could use a following formula to do this:

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$5;MATCH(C8;INDEX($B$2:$G$5;0;MATCH(A8&B8;$B$1:$G$1;0));1))
```

the sheet looks like this (the above formula is in `D8`):

```
    A   B   C   D   E   F   G
1       13F 14F 15F 13M 14M 15M
2   D   0   0   0   0   0   0
3   C   11  12  13  12  13  14
4   B   21  22  23  22  23  24
5   A   31  32  33  32  33  34
6
7   Age Gen Sco Gra
8   15  M   22  C
9   14  F   22  B
10  14  M   22  C
```

The table with grades is in $A$1:$G$5, first row has concatenated age with gender, first column contains grade, and inside the table there is minimum score for the grade, gender and age.